# How to properly update interval from outside of the useEffect that it's wrapped in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use a state number to maintain the time of each interval but when I update the state value the interval remains the same. Here's my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-night-cx2jyj?file=/src/App.tsx:0-855):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState<number>(1);
  const [intervalTime, setIntervalTime] = useState<number>(3000); // every 3 seconds

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSlideIndex((slideIndex) => slideIndex + 1);
      console.log("but interval time is still: " + intervalTime);
    }, intervalTime); //  remains 3 seconds after clicking button
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setIntervalTime(1000);
    console.log("Interval time should be: " + intervalTime);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Counter: {slideIndex}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick()}>
        shorten interval to 1 second
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to add `intervalTime` to the dependency array of the useEffect. `useEffect(() => { ... }, [intervalTime]);`

Comment: @Konrad this isn't a closure issue, just a dependency issue

Comment: @pilchard this question is a textbook example of a stale closure

Comment: If you are only looking at the logged value, yes there is a stale closure. But the issue is that the useEffect needs to be run again in order to reset the interval, using a ref as your duplicate suggests will log correctly, but not reset the interval. And the `setSlideIndex` is correctly avoiding closure issues by using a callback.

Comment: And the solution proposed by the duplicate is poor at best as it suggests duplicating the state value into a ref for the sole purpose of logging it, rather than maintaining a single source of truth ie by using `useCallback`